# how to execute a function in i3 config?

Tags: i3

I want to rename a workspace but retain the workspace number by default, in i3 user guide, I find the following script to do so.

```
bindsym $mod+r exec i3-input -F 'rename workspace to "%s"' -P 'New name: '
```

But the problem is that it doesn't keep workspace number by default, so I have to remember to type the workspace number.

I've found a way to get the number of the focused workspace number with following command, but I don't know how to concat the number to with the input name together in i3 config.

```
i3-msg -t get_workspaces | jq '.[] | select(.focused == true) | .num'
```

So, I'm wondering whether in i3 config file, I can execute some kind of function to concat the workspace number with user input to achieve my purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can.  But, you can always do whatever you want if you create a script and call it with `exec` in your i3-config.  So, for example:

~/bin/i3-rename-workspace (or wherever is convenient for you):

```
N=$(i3-msg -t get_workspaces | jq '.[] | select(.focused == true).num')
i3-input -F "rename workspace to \"$N: %s\"" -P 'New name: '
```

Somewhere in your i3-config:

```
bindsym $mod+r exec i3-rename-workspace
```

Remember to provide the full path to your script, or put it somewhere in i3's `$PATH`.

Comment: You can also add the script directory to the PATH variable, but not using `.bashrc` : https://askubuntu.com/a/920572/75083

Answer (score 1):

You can execute a function from the i3 config, it gets a bit hairy but it works out quite nicely. The key things to remember are any commands with a `,` or `;` need quoted (i.e. every function you can possibly write as it is a required part of the syntax), and if you have additional quotes of the same type inside the command passed to `exec` you need to escape them with `\\` per the [i3 documentation](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#exec).

Personally I wanted a simple shutdown menu without having to create a separate script to maintain and drag around outside my i3 config, I used an inline function definition and call. This is very similar to the recommended way to run external commands in `git` aliases (and is where I had the idea that it would work).

`bindsym $mod+Shift+q exec "bash -c 'f () { res=$(rofi -dmenu < <(echo -en \\"logout\nrestart\nshutdown\\")); case $res in logout) i3-msg exit;; restart) sudo shutdown -r +2;; shutdown) sudo shutdown -P +2;; esac; }; f;'"`

This is a bit dense to unpack, but I define the temporary function `f () {...}; f;'` and call it after. Inside the function I'm feeding in the options to the menu using process substitution and input redirection to capture the selection to a variable `res=$(rofi -dmenu < <(echo -en \\"logout\nrestart\nshutdown\\"))` and note the extra `\\` to escape the inner double quotes.

Finally I'm evaluating the option the user selected via `case` and choosing an action based on that option, with a 2 minute timeout on the restart and shutdown commands so I can abort if somehow I hit the hard to accidentally hit modifiers required to trigger the menu AND select an item rather than just pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit the menu.

After writing this up and realizing how easy it might be to logout and loose all my current windows/layouts, I'm going to add a "no-op" option that appears first in the list and is evaluated last in the `case` statement that maybe will `echo` something funny via `cowsay` or `notify-send`.

Comment: FWIW, I don't see any reason for the function; maybe this was required 7 years ago for some reason in the i3 (or bash) parser? Regardless, as of now, you can just do exec "bash -r 'res=...esac'" without the f wrapper. (Also: I tried your command before reading your full comment and in fact logged myself out, lol.)